# What's the most efficient way to count rows in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

Is it more efficient to use:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users';
$odbcResult = OdbcExec($sql);
@odbc_fetch_row($odbcResult);
$count = @odbc_result($odbcResult, 'count');
```

or to use:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$odbcResult = OdbcExec($sql);    
$count = odbc_num_rows($odbcResult);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The former. The server is doing the work. It may already know the answer without counting,

The later requires all the rows to be returned to your program over the network (and into memory).

Comment: +1 and the answer. "The server is doing the work" - sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM users';
$odbcResult = OdbcExec($sql);
@odbc_fetch_row($odbcResult);
$count = @odbc_result($odbcResult, 'count');
```

or some other index field besides id.  Its a little faster than COUNT(*), but the count method is the way to go.  If you need to do something with the results, method 2 is faster, but only needing count this is the one you want.

-edit- Added keyword of index before field.  True comment below, made the assumption that there was an id index column (should have an index somewhere at any rate)

Comment: Note that `SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM users` returns the number of non-null `id` values.  If there's a NOT NULL constraint on the column, it may not matter, but if there is no NOT NULL constraint, then the DBMS has to do more work to answer this query than it does `COUNT(*)`.  This is even more true if there is no index on the column in question.

Comment: *Its a little faster than COUNT( *)* See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: I haven't tested on MySQL but I found COUNT(1) to be an efficient value on Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Populate a table with 10^x elements with x>=6 and see the time that takes.

Answer (score 2):

The first method is definitely faster. But COUNT(id) being faster than COUNT(*) - questionable. They usually are exactly the same, and there are cases when COUNT(id) is actually slower (see: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/)